# Avoiding nesting subscriptions in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 endpoints:

- 1 endpoint to get current user logged.
- 1 endpoint to get grants of this user.

Actually I use:

```js
this.user
  .subscribe((e) => {
     this.grants.get(e)
        .subscribe((x) => {
            console.log(x)
         })
  })
```

But this is an anti-pattern of Angular 2+/RxJS.

I would like to know how to do this following Angular/RxJS best practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Avoiding nested subscriptions depends on the nature of the observables and how they depend on each other:

#### Co-dependent observables

When an observable (`this.grants.get()`) depends on the notification from another observable (`this.user`), you could use any of the RxJS higher order mapping operators `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap` and `exhaustMap`. Each has their own purpose. You could find the differences between them [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/).

Brief differences b/n them

- `switchMap` - cancel inner observable if the outer observable emits
- `mergeMap` - trigger inner observable for each outer notification (flatten the outer notifications)
- `concatMap` - essentially `mergeMap` with single concurrent request at any time (flattens the outer notifications but emit them in order)
- `exhaustMap` - ignore outer notifications if inner observable hasn't completed

Illustration using `switchMap` operator

```js
this.user.pipe(
  switchMap(e => this.grants.get(e))
).subscribe((x) => {
  console.log(x)
});
```

#### Independent observables

If the observables are independent of each other, you could use RxJS functions like `forkJoin`, `combineLatest` or `zip` to trigger the observables in parallel.

Brief differences b/n them

- `forkJoin`<sup>α</sup> - emit only when all the observables complete
- `combineLatest`<sup>α,β</sup> - emit when **any** of the observables emit (observables w/o emissions will emit old value)
- `zip`<sup>α,β</sup> - emit when **all** of the observables emit

Illustration using [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin)

```js
forkJoin(this.obs1, this.obs2, ...).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res)
);
```

**α** - emits an array of notifications from each observable (eg. `(this.obs1, this.obs2, ...)` will emit `['res from obs1', 'res from obs2', ...]`).

**β** - all observables **should** emit atleast once for the operator to emit

Answer (score 0):

In your code it looks like they have no dependency on each other, because the result from `this.user` is not used in `this.grants.get`but I'll ignore that for now.

You can use the `await` keyword to prevent nesting.

For example you could do the following:

```
const user  = await this.user.toPromise();
const grants = await this.grants.get().toPromise();
```

Comment: `this.grants.get` does use the return value from `this.user`. Also, it isn't necessary to switch from the Observable paradigm to the Promise paradigm, moreover, it will break the thing if `user` emits more than once.

Comment: There are multiple issues here: (1). Unnecessary switch from observables to promise. (2). OP's observables are co-dependent. (3). `toPromise()` method is [being deprecated](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/) in RxJS 7 and will be gone in RxJS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Its working with switchMap.

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major ;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=200")
      .pipe(
        switchMap((mp) => {
          console.log("Requisição 01", mp);
          return this.http.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2");
        }),
        switchMap((it) => {
          console.log("Requisição 02", it);
          return this.http.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/206/");
        })
      )
      .subscribe((d) => console.log("subscribe", d))
  }
}
```