# How to write below code using MergeMap or FlatMap or some better way with rxJs-operators?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have two observable pipes. I need to run one after the other and compare two values equal or not. I tried the below code.This should work, when the first observable value emitted , it should go and take second obserbla value and should comapre it first return value.I need to some expert help , to refator this code better way.

```
   this.selectedUnitDetailModel$.pipe(shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub)).subscribe(
          (res: UnitDetail) =>{
              if(res.unitTwo){
                this.appStore.select(selectUnit).
                pipe(shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub)).subscribe(
                  (unitId: string) => {
                    if(unitId ===  res.unitTwo){
                      this.sameUnit = true;
                    }else{
                      this.sameUnit = false;
                    }
                  });
              }
          }
       );
```

Comment: Try `this.selectedUnitDetailModel$.pipe(withLatestFrom(this.appStore.select(selectUnit)), map(([{unitTwo}, unitId]) => unitTwo === unitId), tap(console.table), shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub)).subscribe(sameUnit => {this.sameUnit = sameUnit;})`.

Comment: what is `shareReplayUntil`?

Comment: @RafiHenig i create Subject and bined all pipe to it , when component destroy , I will unsubscirbe that Subject. actually it used to unsubcribed observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need higher order operators since the observables `this.selectedUnitDetailModel$` and `this.appStore.select(selectUnit)` are independent of each other. Instead you could use functions like `forkJoin`, `combineLatest` or `zip` to get the notifications from them in parallel.

You could find difference b/n these functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921).

Try the following

```js
forkJoin(
  this.selectedUnitDetailModel$.pipe(take(1)),      // <-- complete on first emission
  this.appStore.select(selectUnit).pipe(take(1))    // <-- complete on first emission
).subscribe(
  ([res, unitId]) => this.sameUnit = res.unitTwo === unitId,
  (error) => console.log(error)                     // <-- handle error
);
```

`forkJoin` only emits when the source observables complete, so I've piped in `take(1)` to each observable. The `forkJoin` will now emit on the first emission of each observable and complete. So the need for your `shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub)` is mitigated.

However, if you need to keep the emission stream from the observables open, you could use `combineLatest` or `zip` instead. In this case, you could replace the `take(1)` with your ``shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub)`.

#### Update: continuous stream of  `this.selectedUnitDetailModel$` observable

Like I said before, you could use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin` to enable a continuous stream of data.

Try the following

```js
import { Subject, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

combineLatest(
  this.selectedUnitDetailModel$,
  this.appStore.select(selectUnit)
).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroySub)         // <-- replaced with `takeUntil` operator
).subscribe(
  ([res, unitId]) => this.sameUnit = res.unitTwo === unitId,
  (error) => console.log(error)                     // <-- handle error
);
```

Comment: Thank you ,I will try this. One thing need to know , ' this.selectedUnitDetailModel$' this pipe value is change, then it work in second time ? (think ,  this.selectedUnitDetailModel$ is  List -> i will select one by one item , then need to rechack unit equual or not )

Comment: @uma: No it wont. Like I said before for continuous stream of data you could use `combineLatest` instead. I've updated the answer. Please check if the updated code works for you.

Comment: Michael , I tried second code.combineLatest -> given some deprcated sonar issue.. , and the line ([res:UnitDetail , unitID: string ] , places given compile error like, undefnde :(

Comment: @uma: I'm not sure how this `shareReplayUntil` is implemented. Try to replace it with `takeUntil` operator. It does the same thing that you require: close the open subscription when the component is destroyed. I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: @uma: Also please remove the type definitions from the array `([res, unitId])`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support , i will try to 'combineLatest ' further, now it will given compile error here 'res.unitTwo'  ,i think that pipe may return {} ,undeined and object  :( . The depreate issue also there. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
this.selectedUnitDetailModel$.pipe(shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub),mergeMap(
          (res: UnitDetail) =>{
              if(res.unitTwo){
               return this.appStore.select(selectUnit).
                pipe(shareReplayUntil(this.destroySub),map(
                  (unitId: string) =>  unitId ===  res.unitTwo);
              }
          }
       ).subscribe({
        next: (sameUnit: boolean) => {
           //do something 
        }
       });
```

Comment: you can add return of(false) inside the mergeMap to handle scenario where `res.unitTwo` is false.