# How to add null filter to below mergeMap?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I wrote subscribe service and get value form that and after that call another API. but the first subscription API changed. Now value can be null. so, how can I handle that?. Now code came compile error in, `oc.id`, or can be null.

```
 getE$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(ActionType.A),
switchMapTo(this.store.select(selectP)),
mergeMap((oc) => this.reviewService.findByR(oc.id,
  new Date(new Date()),
  new Date(new Date()), 'A')
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(d => {
      return of(LoadSuccess({ reviews: getReviews(d) }));
    }
    ),
    catchError(error => {
      return of(LoadFailure({ error: error }));
    })
  )
)));
```

Comment: `filter` would go be _between_ `switchMapTo` and `mergeMap`

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you please , how to do it ?

Comment: ' map((oc: Oc) => oc),' I couldn't put filter but I put map between them, is it correct?

Comment: No that won't do what you want. That's an unsafe type conversion. Never put type annotations on the parameters of an **_inline_** callback function (you will see people doing it, specifically in Angular tutorials, and they are doing it wrong.).

Comment: You want this `import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';` then in your method, `getE$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(ActionType.A),
switchMapTo(this.store.select(selectP)), filter((oc): oc is Oc => oc),
mergeMap((oc) => this.reviewService.findByR(oc.id, new Date(new Date()), new Date(new Date()), 'A')` etc.

Comment: I added this 'filter(isNotNullOrUndefined)' :) it was gone that compile errrors ? is it ok ?

Comment: Yeah, that is actually more readable. I can't see your types, so I made a guess at what the filter should look like

Comment: Thank you , I can fix this as your help after long time. If you put it as answer,,,i will accept .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867586/how-to-write-below-code-using-mergemap-or-flatmap-or-some-better-way-with-rxjs-o  . this another issue , had me still not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out the `null` values that the API may now return, we want to place a call to the `filter` operator in our pipeline between the calls to `switchMapTo` and `mergeMap`.

```
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';

getE$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionType.A),
    switchMapTo(this.store.select(selectP)),
    // remove `null` or `undefined` elements
    filter(notNullOrUndefined)
    // safely dereference `oc`
    mergeMap(oc => this.reviewService.findByR(oc.id,
            new Date(new Date()),
            new Date(new Date()), 'A'
        )
        .pipe(
            mergeMap(d => of(LoadSuccess({ reviews: getReviews(d) }))),
            catchError(error => of(LoadFailure({ error: error })))
        )
    )));
```

Where `notNullOrUndefined` is a function tests each element and propagates that information in the form of a type guard. This technique is also useful when working with arrays

```
export function notNullOrUndefined<T>(x: T | null | undefined): x is T {
    return x !== null && x !== undefined;
}
```