# ERROR TypeError: _co.userData is undefined In angular 7 when I try to use property binding for value

Tags: angular

I know questions likes this have been asked already but i am not getting any good result. I search a lot about this but did not get any luck that's why I am posting this.

**I am getting error when I try to show the value in the input field using the variable using property binding.**

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.userData is undefined
```

**component.ts**

```
export class PlaceOrderComponent implements OnInit {

  userData: User
  orderSummary: any
  total: number

  constructor(private userServ: UserService, private cartServ: CartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.userServ.getUserData();
    this.userServ.userData.subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.userData = data;
        this.userServ.getOrderSummary(this.userData.id).subscribe(
          res => { this.orderSummary = res.message[0]},
          err => console.log(err)
        )

        this.cartServ.getCartTotal(this.userData.id).subscribe(
          res => {this.total = res.message[0][0].total},
          err => console.log(err)
        )
        console.log(this.userData)
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<form 
          #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
            <h5>Shipping Address</h5>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control"
                [value]="userData.firstName"
                ngModel
                name="firstName"
                required
                #firstName="ngModel">
                <span
                style="color: red" 
                *ngIf="!firstName.valid && firstName.touched">Required</span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control"
                ngModel
                name="lastName"
                required
                #lastName="ngModel">
                <span
                style="color: red" 
                *ngIf="!lastName.valid && lastName.touched">Required</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input 
              type="email" 
              class="form-control"
              ngModel
              name="emailAddress"
              email
              required
              #emailAddress="ngModel">
              <span
              style="color: red" 
              *ngIf="!emailAddress.valid && emailAddress.touched">Required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contact">Contact</label>
              <input 
              type="text" 
              class="form-control"
              ngModel
              name="contact"
              required
              #contact="ngModel">
              <span
              style="color: red" 
              *ngIf="!contact.valid && contact.touched">Required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea 
                    class="form-control" 
                    id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" 
                    rows="3"
                    ngModel
                    required
                    name="address"
                    #address="ngModel"></textarea>
                    <span
                    style="color: red" 
                    *ngIf="!address.valid && address.touched">Required</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            <button 
            type="submit" 
            class="btn btn-primary placeorder-btn"
            [disabled]="!form.valid">Place Order</button>
          </form>
```

I am using template driver form may be there is some other way to show the value in input field using the variable.

I also try to use `two-way binding [(ngModel)]="userData.firstName"` but still getting the same error.

So please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues.

1. Try to avoid nested subscriptions. Instead you could use RxJS higher order operator like `switchMap` for dependent observables and function like `forkJoin` for independent observables. You could find info about other operators and functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921).

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
  this.userServ.getUserData();

  this.userServ.userData.pipe(
    switchMap((data: any) => {
      this.userData = data;
      return forkJoin(
        this.userServ.getOrderSummary(data.id), 
        this.cartServ.getCartTotal(data.id)
      );
    })
  ).subscribe(
    ([summary, total]) => {
      this.orderSummary = summary.message[0];
      this.total = total.message[0][0].total;
      console.log(this.userData);
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  );
}
```

2. The variable `this.userData` is initialized asynchronously. So by the time the `ngModel` binding is interpreted, it is still undefined. In this situation you could use the [safe navigation operator `?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#safe-navigation-operator) that checks if the object is defined before trying to access it's properties.

Try the following

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  [value]="userData?.firstName" 
  ngModel 
  name="firstName" 
  required
  #firstName="ngModel"
>
```

Comment: This is working now form have value without error but form is still invalid I have to made some changes to the form to make it valid, so do have any idea for that. But thanks for the help you suggestion really worked out.