# How to map data correctly before subscription?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have following function:

```
    this.localStorage.getItem('user').subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.authSrv.getOrders(this.user.einsender).pipe(map(orders => {
        map(order => { order["etz"] = "23"; return order})
        return orders;
      })).subscribe(orders => {
        this.orders = orders;
        this.completeOrders = orders;
        console.log(orders);
        this.waitUntilContentLoaded = true;
      })
    })
```

The result without the map is:

```
[{id: 1, etz: "21"}]
```

With the map from above I try to enter the array, then the order and in the order I try to change the `etz` property but somehow nothing changes. Can someone look over?
I appreciate any help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `order.etz = "23"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see multiple issues here.

1. Try to avoid nested subscriptions. Instead you could use one of the RxJS higher order mapping operators like [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap). You could find differences b/n different higher order mapping operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990) and [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/).
2. To adjust each element of the array you need to use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method in addition to the RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator.
3. You could use JS [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to adjust some of the properties of the object and retain other properties.

Try the following

```js
this.localStorage.getItem('user').pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    this.user = user;
    return this.authSrv.getOrders(this.user.einsender).pipe(
      map(orders => orders.map(order => ({...order, order['etz']: '23'})))
    });
  })
).subscribe(
  orders => {
    this.orders = orders;
    this.completeOrders = orders;
    console.log(orders);
    this.waitUntilContentLoaded = true;
  },
  error => {
    // good practice to handle HTTP errors
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` is an operator that goes in a pipe like this:

```js
someObs$.pipe(map(arg => { return 'something'}));
```

You've done this:

```js
someObs$.pipe(map(arg => { 
    map(arg => { return 'something' })     // this line here does nothing
    return arg; 
}));
```

It doesn't make any sense to use `map` **inside** the function you've given to `map`