# RxJS array of HTTP observables: fire next only after previous completes

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have an array of observables (HTTP POST requests) that I need to send off to an API after a specific event. The following is a simplified example of the approach, where I use `concat` so I can leverage success, error and complete callbacks.

```
// build up an array of stored POST requests to fire off later
// array is indeterminate length, could be 1 request could be 1,000
let requests = [ req1, req2, req3, req4 ];

concat(...requests).subscribe(
  success => ... handle success ...
  error => ... handle error ...
  () => ... handle completion ...
);
```

The issue is the concat basically sends all the requests at once, raising the potential for concurrency issues in the API consuming the requests. This issue should be resolved if I am able to fire the requests off one-by-one rather than all at once. I've determined that a `forEach` loop is not an option.

Is there an RxJS approach such that `req2` only emits after `req1` completes and `req3` emits only after `req2` completes and so on? I've been reviewing the RxJS docs but have yet to find anything that fits this scenario.

Comment: Use async await for dependencies using closures. Convert observable to promises to get it done.

Comment: "The issue is the concat basically sends all the requests at once" -> `concat` should fire the observables sequentially, only moving on the subsequent requests after the first one has completed. [Example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat#examples)

Comment: Your code with `concat` should work as intended. If it doesn't please provide a stackblitz that's reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) function and higher order mapping operator [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap).

Try the following

```js
from(requests).pipe(
  concatMap(req => req)
).subscribe(
  success => ... handle success ...
  error => ... handle error ...
  () => ... handle completion ...
);
```

Without the `concatMap` operator the request elements of the array would be verbatim emitted as observables instead of being triggered. You could find differences b/n higher order mapping operators in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990).

Comment: @RafiHenig: `concat`'s supposed to send the requests sequentially. But you say _"(it) basically sends all the requests at once"_. And without seeing the nature of the requests, my answer is the next alternative I could come up with. It ensures the emissions are sequential. You could see the differences in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kfheyu?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: your example in stackblitz helped me a lot thanks !