# Angular Resolver with related Observables using withLatest

Tags: angular, rxjs, resolve

The second observable of my resolver has to use the result of the first observable. I couldn't fiure out how to pass that data to the second observable :

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<[Project[], Owner]> {
    const currentEmail = this.CurrentUserEmail();
    return this.searchService.genericSearchApi('/api/searchproject', ...[//I need to pass the user here.]]).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(
            this.userService.getUserByEmail(currentEmail)

        )
    );
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep. Michael's answer does too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use any of the RxJS higher order [mapping operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990) in cases where an observable depends on the emission of another observable.

Illustration using `switchMap` operator

```js
resolve(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<[Project[], Owner]> {
  const currentEmail = this.CurrentUserEmail();
  return this.userService.getUserByEmail(currentEmail).pipe(
    switchMap(user => this.searchService.genericSearchApi('/api/searchproject', user))
  );
}
```

Comment: There's indeed no need for `withLatest` thanks for the link :)