# How to handle ngrx let with many subscribes as ng-container inside ng-container?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I start using [ngrx let](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let) to using plain objects.

The problem is when I use a lot of observables in my component, I end up with the code which is seems bad (ng-container inside ng-container inside ng-container inside ng-container ...):

```
<ng-container *ngrxLet="obs1$ as obs1">
 <ng-container *ngrxLet="obs2$ as obs2">
  <ng-container *ngrxLet="obs3$ as obs3">
   <ng-container *ngrxLet="obs4$ as obs4">

    <app-comp [data]="obs1" ..>..</app-comp>
    <app-comp2 [data]="obs1" [data2]="obs3"..>..</app-comp2>
    <app-comp3 [data]="obs1" ..>..</app-comp3>
    <app-comp4 [data]="obs1" ..>..</app-comp4>
    <app-comp5 [data]="obs4" [data11]="obs1" ..>..</app-comp5>
    <app-comp6 [data]="obs2" ..>..</app-comp6>
    <app-comp7 [data]="obs3" ..>..</app-comp7>
  </app-number>
</ng-container>
```

Is there a better way to handle this syntax?

Answer (score 6):

```html
<ng-container *ngrxLet="{obs1: obs1$, obs2: obs2$, obs3: obs3$} as context">
    <app-comp1 [data]="context.obs1" …>…</app-comp1>
    <app-comp2 [data]="context.obs2" …>…</app-comp2>
    <app-comp3 [data]="context.obs3" …>…</app-comp3>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3):

ngrxLet does not seem to support that feature, you could use combineLatest as mentioned in previous answer or try some trcik i used with *ngIf

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{
  obs1: obs1$ | async,
  obs2: obs2$ | async,
  obs3: obs3$ | async,
  obs4: obs4$ | async
} as data">
    <app-comp [data]="data.obs1"></app-comp>
    <app-comp2 [data]="data.obs1" [data2]="data.obs3"></app-comp2>
    <app-comp3 [data]="data.obs1"></app-comp3>
    <app-comp4 [data]="data.obs1"></app-comp4>
    <app-comp5 [data]="data.obs4" [data11]="data.obs1"></app-comp5>
    <app-comp6 [data]="data.obs2"></app-comp6>
    <app-comp7 [data]="data.obs3"></app-comp7>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the observables in the controller using RxJS functions like `combineLatest`, `zip` and `forkJoin`. Each has a specific mechanism and you could find the differences between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990).

Illustration using `combineLatest`

Controller

```js
combined$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.combined$ = combineLatest(
    obs1$.pipe(startWith(null)),
    obs2$.pipe(startWith(null)),
    obs3$.pipe(startWith(null)),
    obs4$.pipe(startWith(null))
  ).map(([obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4]) => ({  // <-- `map` emits a user-friendly object
    obs1: obs1,
    obs2: obs2,
    obs3: obs3,
    obs4: obs4
  }));
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngrxLet="combined$ as data">
  <app-comp [data]="data?.obs1" ..>..</app-comp>
  <app-comp2 [data]="data?.obs1" [data2]="data?.obs3"..>..</app-comp2>
  <app-comp3 [data]="data?.obs1" ..>..</app-comp3>
  <app-comp4 [data]="data?.obs1" ..>..</app-comp4>
  <app-comp5 [data]="data?.obs4" [data11]="data?.obs1" ..>..</app-comp5>
  <app-comp6 [data]="data?.obs2" ..>..</app-comp6>
  <app-comp7 [data]="data?.obs3" ..>..</app-comp7>
</ng-container>
```

However there is a caveat. `combineLatest` and `zip` won't start emitting unless each of the source observable has emitted at least once. We can enforce it using the `startWith` operator like shown here. But then you need to make sure the first value (`null` here) doesn't affect the data binding. You could of course replace `*ngrxLet` with `*ngIf` to avoid emitting the `null`, but then you'd lose the benefits of `*ngrxLet`.