# Best way for multiple HTTP Request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to send 2 HTTP requests one by one; if the first one is succeeds, send the second one, if not display the corresponding error message regarding to the first request.

I am planning to use something like that, but not sure if it is the best option for this scenario:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  loadedCharacter: {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/api/people/1').subscribe(character => {
      this.http.get(character.homeworld).subscribe(homeworld => {
        character.homeworld = homeworld;
        this.loadedCharacter = character;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I have different requests e.g. PUT and CREATE also using this approach. I know there are other ways e.g. `forkjoin`, `mergemap`, but if this one solves my problem seems to be more readable. Any idea?

Comment: [This may give you some inspiration](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)

Comment: @Picci Seems to be very useful, I will definitely read. But for now, I need an urgent solution. Any suggestion pls?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) is a short answer that I wrote on handling nested observables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, your code works and that's great - you can leave it as is and everything will be fine.

On the other hand, there is a way for multiple improvements that will help you and your colleagues in future:

1. try to move http-related logic to the service instead of calling http in the components - this will help you to split the code into view-related logic and the business/fetching/transformation-related one.
2. try to avoid nested `subscribe`s - not only you ignore the mighty power of `Observable`s but also tie the code to a certain flow without an ability to reuse these lines somewhere in the application. Returning the `Observable` might help you with *"sharing"* the results of the request or transforming it in some way.
3. `flatMap/mergeMap`, `concatMap` and `switchMap` work in a different way, providing you an ability to control the behaviour the way you want. Though, for `http.get()` they work almost similar, it's a good idea to start learning those combining operators as soon as possible.
4. think about how you'll handle the errors in this case - what will happen if your first call will result an error? `Observable`s have a powerful mechanism of dealing with them, while `.subscribe` allows you to handle an error only in one way.

An example using the `switchMap`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  loadedCharacter: {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const character$ = this.http.get('/api/people/1').pipe(
      tap(character => this.characterWithoutHomeworld = character), // setting some "in-between" variable
      switchMap(character => {
        return this.http.get(character.homeworld).pipe(
            map(homeworld => {
                    return {
                        ...character,
                        homeworld: homeworld
                    }
                }
            )
        )
      }),
      catchError(errorForFirstOrSecondCall => {
        console.error('An error occurred: ', errorForFirstOrSecondCall);
        // if you want to handle this error and return some empty data use:
        // return of({});
        
        // otherwise: 
        throw new Error('Error: ' + errorForFirstOrSecondCall.message);
      })
);

    // you can either store this variable as `this.character$` or immediately subscribe to it like:
    character$.subscribe(loadedCharacter => {
        this.loadedCharacter = loadedCharacter;
    }, errorForFirstOrSecondCall => {
       console.error('An error occurred: ', errorForFirstOrSecondCall);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations. Actually that's why I asked this question even if it would work. So, in this case could you post the code above by usimng one of your suggested ways e.g. `flatMap/mergeMap` etc.? I would prefer a most readable way so that I can manipulate the results easily.

Comment: You get max upvotes, but it would be better to suggest some usage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PragDopravy I've added an example with `switchMap`

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure if I explained the scenario very well. Asssume that I have 2 different API call for updating data and; **1.** In each call I want to get the response of that call and catch the error related to that call.  **2.** If the first call is failed, I want to break and does not execute the second call after getting error or checking response data. So, I think it seems to be better to use `switchMap` as you gave. So, could you please update your answer according to the scenario I explained here?

Comment: The scenario above with fail on either first call error or second call error. The errors can be caught either in `.subscribe`'s callback or at the very end of the `character$`'s `.pipe` (`catchError`). The second call won't be performed if the first one results an error. If you want to set some data from the first call simply move it to a separate variable or use `.tap(data => this.data = data)` (but from your example you almost completely ignore the response of the first call)

Comment: Could you updet the answer regarding to the scenario above? If it is possible I wouls like to use `switchMap` in that example.

Comment: Done - `switchMap`, `in-between` variable storing and `catchError` are present in the example

Comment: Thnanks for detailed explanation. **1.** As far as I see, one catch block is would be enough for multiple calls or `switchMap` blocks. Is that true? **2.** On the other hand, what if I need to make more calls? In that case should I add multiple `switchMap` block just below the one one your code? **3.** What should I use to finish the stream? There are `return NEVER`, `return EMPTY`, etc, but I have no idea about which one I should do?

Comment: Yes, `catchError` will catch all the errors if it's placed in the end. More calls - more `switchMaps`, that's also true (simply copy the first one). You don't need to finish the stream - it's auto-finished by the Angular's `http`

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to finish the stream at any point e.g. aplying a logic or the call result is not suitable for the condition, I think I should finalize. Otherwise the result will pass to the next stream (next `switchMap`). Is that true? **the second question** is when I do not use `return NEVER` or `return `serv,ce.method(..)` it gives error. So, do I have to use one of them in the `switchMap` ?

Comment: Try to specify your scenarios more clearly - clear steps and what do you wan't to achieve. The chain of `pipe-able` operators can solve any task related to the stream while some `if`s inside `switchMap` can control the flow of your logic. From the example above - there is no correct way of `finalising` the stream, you should think of splitting them into more variables and combine them the way you want. Also, your `switchMap` can return either `this.http.get` or `of(null)` if you don't want to perform some http calls depending on the condition.

Answer (score 3):

2 nested subscriptions are never a way to go. I recommend this approach:

```
this.http.get('/api/people/1').pipe(
  switchMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld).pipe(
    map(homeworld => ({ ...character, homeworld })),
  )),
).subscribe(character => this.loadedCharacter = character);
```

---

Edit: For your university

```
this.http.get('/api/people/1').pipe(
  switchMap(character => this.http.get(character.university).pipe(
    map(university => ({ ...character, university})),
  )),
).subscribe(character => this.loadedCharacter = character);
```

Or even chain university and homeworld requests

```
this.http.get('/api/people/1').pipe(
  switchMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld).pipe(
    map(homeworld => ({ ...character, homeworld })),
    // catchError(err => of({ ...character, homeworld: dummyHomeworld })),
  )),
  switchMap(character => this.http.get(character.university).pipe(
    map(university => ({ ...character, university})),
  )),
).subscribe(character => this.loadedCharacter = character);
```

Comment: Could you please and an update to your answer for this scenario? First you get a person as above and then update hirs or her university name by callling another request?

Comment: Thnaks a lot. Does it continue to execute the second call even if there is an error at the first one? On the other hand, how can I handle errors for each of these calls?

Comment: By the way voted up, thanks for your helps. I would be appreciated if you explain a little bit how it works also. Regards.

Comment: With this chain the second call wouldn't be executed if the first fails. But you could add a `catchError` after the `map` operator, I again updated my answer, I only added an example as a comment. With the `catchError` the outer stream would continue.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I need some clarification. Actually you send get requests and add the returned `homeworld` to the `character` array. Is that true? But actually I want to send firts request add and then by getting its id, send another request to add another record (lets assume that add a person and then automatically add default education info as primary school). So, if you would not mind could you pls add 3 rd scenario for that? The second would also be useful for someone else and it is good idea to keep it. I think your approach is very useful and thats why I want to use it :) regards.

Comment: If you have time and add an update I would be appreciated and will use that approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a solution using `switchmap` and `forkJoin` for easier chaining and error handling. this will help keep the code clean in case the chain keeps growing into a deep nest.

```js
    this.http
      .get("/api/people/1'")
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          // handle error
        }),
        switchMap((character) => {
          return forkJoin({
            character: of(character),
            homeworld: this.http.get(character.homeworld)
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(({ character, homeworld }) => {
        character.homeworld = homeworld;
        this.loadedCharacter = character;
      });
```

EDIT: Scenario 2

```js
this.http
      .get("/api/people/1")
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log("e1", err);
        }),
        switchMap((character) => {
          return forkJoin({
            character: of(character),
            homeworld: this.http.get(character.homeworld).pipe(
              catchError((err) => {
                console.log("e2", err);
              })
            )
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe(({ character, homeworld }) => {
        character.homeworld = homeworld;
        this.loadedCharacter = character;
      });
```

You can chain a catch error or add a separate function for error handling without it invoking the next API call. but I would recommend abstracting the backend logic to an angular service and using this method. which would help retain an easy to read structure.

Comment: Seems to be good instead of using nested ones. Thanks, voted up.

Comment: Could you also please add another usage with this approach as following? At first request updating a record and then according to the returned value (eg. status code)send another requesr for adding another record and display message?

Comment: so you only want to send the second request if the status code is lets say 200?

Comment: Not actually, I mean that at first call add a record and then send another request for updating another record. But while this, I want to handle errors for each request and if there is an error in the first request I want to break and just display erros message without executing the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the first request was successful or not by checking the status code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/api/people/1').subscribe((character: HttpResponse<any>) => {
      // here you should look for the correct status code to check, in this example it's 200
      if (character.status === 200) {
        this.http.get(character.homeworld).subscribe(homeworld => {
          character.homeworld = homeworld;
          this.loadedCharacter = character;
        });
      } else {
        // character is gonna contain the error
        console.log(character)
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Nested `subscribe` are not considered idiomatic with RxJs

Comment: Thanks for help, but I think this approach is not suggested.