# How to change value of object in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, rxjs

I have service like this :

```
getLastStatus(id): Observable<string> {
        let url_detail = this.apiurl + `/${id}`;
        return this.http.get<any>(url_detail, this.httpOptions).pipe(
            map(data => {
                var status = data['data'].reduce((item, curr) => {
                    return item.id < curr.id ? curr : item;
                }).status.title;

                return status;

            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }


getData(){
        return this.http.get<DataModel[]>(this.apiurl, this.httpOptions).pipe(
            tap(data=> {
                data.map(d=>{
                    this.getLastStatus(d.id).subscribe(s=>{
                        d.status = s;
                    });
                });
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
```

I want to update value of status from the result of json object. But, when I subscribe getData() like this, the value of status not updated.

```
this.myService.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data)
      data.map(d=>{
         console.log("status ", d.status) //value of status not updated
      })
    });
```

What's should i do with my code? Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no JSON involved in this question. The Angular infrastructure takes care of all of the conversion from the JSON text format to JavaScript objects needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the statuses are obtained asynchronously. You could avoid nested subscriptions using RxJS higher order mapping operator like `switchMap`. And since you have a bunch of observables to trigger at once, you could use the RxJS `forkJoin` function.

I'm also using [JS destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to retain the properties of the object except to adjust or include the `status` property.

Try the following

```js
getData() {
  return this.http.get<DataModel[]>(this.apiurl, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    switchMap(data =>
      forkJoin(
        data.map(d => 
          this.getLastStatus(d.id).pipe(
            map(status => ({ ...d, d.status: status }))
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

You could also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990) for more info on `switchMap` operator and `forkJoin` function.