# ForkJoin - ForLoop - Handle some logic after each subscription and some after all obseravables resolved

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a http call inside a forloop. The APICall will return a HTML response which i am using it render on the page.

Now I also have a requirement where after all API calls's are completed i have to perform some logic to update some data on the backend.

I understand we can use a forkjoin operator to capture array of observables and then update the BE data. But i am unable to understand how to handle the requirement that has to be completed on each subscription.

```
for(let item of Items){
    this.myService
            .getMyItemData(item.key)
            .pipe(
              takeUntil(this.destroyed),
              distinctUntilChanged(),
              catchError((e: Error) => {
                this.logger.logError('Error loading', e);
                return of('An Error Occurred');
              })
            ).subscribe((resp) => {
```

**//How can i handle this subscription when using forkjoin ??**

```
             this.elementRef.nativeElement.html = resp;
    }) 
}
```

Now after getting all the itemData i want to perform an update for the Backend. For this i am thinking of using a forkJoin to capture all observables data. But at the same time i want to use the subscription code to render the HTML. Can someone help how can i achieve that.

****Reference for my forkJoin Code*****

```
let arrayOfObservables  = Items.map((item) => this.myService
                .getMyItemData(item.key))

let dataSource =  Rx.Observable.forkJoin(arrayOfObservables);

dataSource.subscribe((resp) => {
  // update my BE data
})
```

Comment: Does each response from `getMyItemData()` need to update a different `elementRef`?

Comment: @BizzyBob yes, i believe yes each response is different elementref. So basically i am using this itemdatacomponent as a child component inside a loop in  parent component html conditionally.  So suppose i am displaying 20 result rows on the page then around 5 will be the HTML from the child component (itemDataComponent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forkJoin` will only emit when all the source observable complete. Given the usage of `distinctUntilChanged()` operator I assume each observable is a stream of notifications.

1. In that case `combineLatest` is better fit than `forkJoin`. It'll emit when any of the source observable emits. But note: each observable should've emitted at least once for the subscription to be triggered. If you wish to trigger the subscription before some observables haven't emitted yet, you could pipe `startWith(null)` to each source observable.
   Also look into RxJS `zip` function. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) is a quick run down b/n different functions.
2. To perform something after each emission, you could either `tap` operator (if performing side-effects) or `map` operator (to transform the data).

```js
import { of, combineLatest, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, takeUntil, startWith, distinctUntilChanged, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

combineLatest(
  Items.map((item) => 
    this.myService.getMyItemData(item.key).pipe(
      startWith(null),           // <-- use conditionally (see above)
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap((resp) => {
        if (!!resp) {            // <-- avoid `null` from `startWith`
          this.elementRef.nativeElement.html = resp;
        }
      }),
      catchError((e: Error) => {
        this.logger.logError('Error loading', e);
        return of('An Error Occurred');
      })
    )
  )
).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroyed)
).subscribe((resp) => {
  // update my BE data
});
```

Comment: Combine Latest worked for me in this scenario. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question:

> How to handle some logic after each subscription and some after all observables resolved

If I understand correctly, you want to create a single `dataSource` that represents data from multiple different calls.  You want to do something when each individual call returns (Work #1), and do something else when all calls have completed (Work #2).

To perform your Work #1, you can use the [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) operator in the definition of your "individual" call. `tap` allows you to execute code whenever a value passes through the observable stream.  If multiple values will be passing through and you only want to run logic when the observable completes, you can use [`finalize`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/finalize) instead.

[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) creates the `dataSource` composed of many individual calls and it will emit an array of all the results once they have all completed.  So, you can easily do your Work #2 in the subscribe.  However, you can also do your work in `tap` or `finalize` as well:

```js
individual$ = key => this.myService.getMyItemData(key).pipe(
    tap(result => console.log(`call #${key} DONE`)) // <-- Do Work #1
);

dataSource$ = forkJoin(Items.map(i => individual$(i.key)).pipe(
    tap(allResults => console.log('all calls DONE')) // <-- Do Work #2
);

dataSource$.subscribe();
```

A single subscription to `dataSource$` will execute the logic for the individual calls (Work #1) and the logic for "all calls" (Work #2).

It seems like it would get messy to manage lots of `elementRefs` in the controller and manipulate the DOM using `this.elementRef.nativeElement.html`.  Depending on your scenario, it may be simpler to bind to the `innerHTML` property using `*ngFor`:

```html
<ul *ngIf="dataSource$ | async as items">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items" [innerHTML]="item"></li>
</ul>
```

Notice if you use the `async` pipe, you don't even need to subscribe in your controller.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66534252?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) sample.