# Angular 11 - subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of a complete callback

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an `Angular` application in which errors are beginning to appear in the `subscribe` that they are deprecated.

This is my subscribe:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.clienteId = +params['clienteId'];
      this.isNew = !this.clienteId;
      if (!this.isNew) {
        this.clienteService.get(this.clienteId).subscribe(c => {
          this.cliente = c;
          this.formNuevo.patchValue(this.cliente);
        });
      }
    });
```

This is the `client-service.ts` (`get`):

```
public get(idClient: number): Observable<Client> {
      return this.http.get<Client>(`${PREFIX}/${idClient}`);
    }
```

This is the error of the new subscribe:

[image]

-> `'clienteId'` : `object access via string literals is disallowed (no-string-literal)tslint(1)`

-> `subscribe`: `subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of a complete callback (deprecation)tslint(1)`

How can I solve the problem and apply the changes to this subscribe?

Comment: Are you possibly using a `null` for `error` or `complete` callback?

Comment: The error is caused by TSLint but I can't fix the deprecated problem. The call works fine

Comment: please provide the code of clienteservice.get

Comment: I have added the get method of the service

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Use higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to map from one observable to another. Try to avoid nested subscriptions.
2. The "error" is mostly caused by trying to send one or the other callbacks for subscription while specifying `null` for other ones. For eg. using `next` and `complete` with `null` for `error`. It could be solved by sending an observer object that explicitly specifies the callbacks.

Try the following

```js
import { iif, NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.route.params.pipe(
  switchMap(params => {
    this.clienteId = +params['clienteId'];
    this.isNew = !this.clienteId;
    return iif(                        // <-- `iif` for conditional mapping
      () => !this.isNew,
      this.clienteService.get(this.clienteId),
      NEVER                            // <-- don't emit if condition fails
    );
  })
).subscribe({
  next: c => {
    this.cliente = c;
    this.formNuevo.patchValue(this.cliente);
  },
  error: error => {
    // handle error
  },
  complete: () => {
    console.log('Request complete');
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand the new way to do it but I will keep reading some more information, because in the current subscribe I use two subscribe but now there is only one. Even so the subscribe keeps giving me the same error

Comment: @synffryd: Could you show a screenshot of the error?

Comment: I have added an image to the question with the two errors that the new code shows

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I think you might be a victim of this issue (though relatively old): https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4159#issuecomment-491034939

Comment: From what I'm seeing, the subscribe currently has to be done in the following way: ``.subscribe({
   next: this.handleUpdateResponse.bind(this),
   error: this.handleError.bind(this)
});``. In this case there is a subscribe, but how do I do if I have a subscribe inside another subscribe?

Comment: @synffryd: It's generally inelegant to have nested subscriptions. It leads to multiple open subscriptions. It's better to use a mapping operator like `switchMap` as shown here. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you were hit by [this TypeScript bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43053) because your observer pattern looks correct. The bug has since been fixed. I don't believe the VS Code patch is live yet, but it should be pretty soon.