# How to make sequential service call on success of first service response in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-services, angular-components

I need to make multiple service call in angular one after other. need to pass the first
service call respose as input to another service.

Here is my component:

```
 Demo(): any {
        if (fileToUpload) {
          this._voiceboxService.upload(fileToUpload)
          .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.text=res.prediction
              console.log(res);
          });
      }
      else
          console.log("FileToUpload was null or undefined.");
    }
}
```

Here is my Service: i need to call all three service on success of one service and need to
pass first service resposnse as input for next service

```
          upload(fileToUpload: any) {
            let input = new FormData();
            input.append("file", fileToUpload);
           return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:5001/', input)
         
          language(data: any) {
           return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:5002', data)
          }
    
        getDetails(data: any) {
           return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:5003', data)
          }
```

Comment: Use `susbscribe` and call other method in the body of `subscribe`

Comment: `concatMap` is probably the best operator in this case. You can find inspiration in [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Answer (score 1):

Use mergeMap.
I assume you want to do this in your component:

```
   this._voiceboxService.upload(fileToUpload).pipe(mergeMap(upload => 
       this._voiceboxService.language(upload)
          .pipe(mergeMap(language => this._voiceboxService.getDetails(language))
   ))).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.text=res.prediction
        console.log(res);
   });
```

You can use map in the end organize your final value result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the RxJS higher order mapping operators like `switchMap` to map from one observable to another. You could find differences between different mapping operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921).

**Service**

```js
upload(fileToUpload: any) {
  let input = new FormData();
  input.append("file", fileToUpload);
  return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:5001/', input).pipe(
    switchMap(res => this.language(res)),  // <-- `res` = response from previous request
    switchMap(res => this.getDetails(res)) // <-- `res` = response from `this.language()`
  );
}

language(data: any) {
  return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:5002', data)
}

getDetails(data: any) {
  return this.http.post<any>('https://localhost:5003', data)
}
```

**Component**

```js
Demo(): any {
  if (fileToUpload) {
    this._voiceboxService.upload(fileToUpload).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {                // <-- `res` = response from `getDetails()`
        this.text = res.prediction
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        // handle errors
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("FileToUpload was null or undefined.");
  }
}
```