# How to resolve Angular error - You provided ‘undefined’ where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.?

Tags: angular

My code is returning the following error -

```
You provided ‘undefined’ where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

My Code -

```
    IdSelection() {
    if (this.selection.selected.length > 0) {
      this.showProcessingFlag = true;
      from(this.selection.selected)
        .pipe(
          map((element) => element.Id),
          mergeMap((element) =>
            this.TaskService.getDetails(element, 0, '%27%27')
          ),
          filter((res) => res['commentId'] != null),
          mergeMap((res) => from(res['commentId'])),
          mergeMap((data) =>
            this.TaskService.getCmntDetails(0, Number(data), '%27%27')
          ),
          mergeMap((innerRes) => 
            innerRes['commentRevId'].forEach(element => {
            this.dataToBeSent += element + '/' + innerRes['origReviewerId'] + ',';
          })),
          toArray()
        )
        .subscribe((res) => {
          setTimeout(() => {   
            console.log(res);
            this.showProcessingFlag = false;
          }, 10);
        });
    } else {
    }
  }
```

I added toArray at the end but that didnt work , can anyone help me with the solution ? TIA

Comment: try to return value from mergeMap.

Comment: Did , but throwing error

Comment: @Aviad P. Can you look into it ?

Comment: @angular_code Each mergeMap needs observable stream as an input

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Can you please explain how to do that ? would be of great help

Comment: @angular_code make demo in stackblitz to understand it more.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda That would be tuff to create as services are involved . It is throwing error at  mergeMap((innerRes) => 
        innerRes['commentRevId'].forEach(element => {
        this.dataToBeSent += element + '/' + innerRes['origReviewerId'] + ',';
      })),
      toArray()
    )

Comment: well try to use map instead of forEach  ` innerRes['commentRevId'map].forEach(element`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239071/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-angular-code).