# How to chain observables like using Promises or async/await?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

Let's imagine I have this code using async/await that's working very well:

```js
async function getMeSomething() : Promise<Something> {
  // some async code
}

async function getMeStuff() : Promise<Stuff> {
  // some async code
}

async function getMeSomethingWithStuff: Promise<SomethingWithStuff> {
  const something: Something = await getMeSomething();
  const stuff: Stuff = await getMeStuff();
  return new SomethingWithStuff(something, stuff);
}
```

This code could effectively be written with promises, like any code using async/await (it's just longer):

```js
// this is strictly equivalent to previous example, including exception management
function getMeSomethingWithStuff: Promise<SomethingWithStuff> {
  let something;
  return getMeSomething().then((res) => {
    something = res;
    return getMeStuff();
  }).then((stuff) => {
    return new SomethingWithStuff(something, stuff);
  });
}
```

When calling the third function it will call the first one and second one, combine the results and return me the final result in a way that the caller of the third function has no idea which underlying functions were called:

```js
const somethingWithStuff: SomethingWithStuff = getMeSomethingWithStuff();
// we have the result, we don't care how we got it, the logic is completely encapsulated
```

How could we write an equivalent code using only rxjs ?

```js
// the following two functions are already defined and we can't redefine them
function getMeSomething() : Observable<Something> {
  // some async code
}

function getMeStuff() : Observable<Stuff> {
  // some async code
}

// we want to define this function that should return an observable
function getMeSomethingWithStuff: Observable<SomethingWithStuff> {
  // what's the code ?
}
```

The rules:

- No cheating with promises, async/await or conversion between observables and promises, it must only use rxjs
- Exceptions must be correctly handled

It may seem a trivial question but I couldn't find an answer by myself despite reading carefully the documentation of rxjs and a lot of tutorials.

Comment: from RXJS convert promise to observable. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from

Comment: You can't, that's in the rules :D.

Comment: When you enter code, you can apply syntax highlighting like so https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to use function like `forkJoin` to trigger multiple observables in parallel and one of the higher order mapping operators like `switchMap` to map from one observable to another.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) for brief descriptions of `forkJoin` function and `switchMap` operator.

#### Option 1: Parellel

```js
// the following two functions are already defined and we can't redefine them
function getMeSomething() : Observable<Something> {
  // some async code
}

function getMeStuff() : Observable<Stuff> {
  // some async code
}

function getMeSomethingWithStuff: Observable<SomethingWithStuff> {
  return forkJoin({
    something: getMeSomething(),
    stuff: getMeStuff()
  }).pipe(
    switchMap((res: any) => 
      new SomethingWithStuff(res.something, res.stuff)
    )
  );
}
```

#### Option 2: Serial

Use multiple higher order mapping operators

```js
function getMeSomethingWithStuff: Observable<SomethingWithStuff> {
  return getMeSomething().pipe(
    switchMap(something => getMeStuff().pipe(
      map(stuff => ({ something, stuff })
    ),
    switchMap((res: any) => 
      new SomethingWithStuff(res.something, res.stuff)
    )
  );
}
```

**Update:** add serial observable trigger

Comment: Yeah, not a bad answer. It performs in parallel rather than sequentially but it still gave me enough hints to write my own sequential version:

```
function getMeSomethingWithStuff: Observable<SomethingWithStuff> {
  let something: Something
  return getMeSomething().pipe(
    map((res: Something) => {
      something = res
      return getMeStuff()
    }),
    switchAll(),
    map(res: Stuff) => 
      new SomethingWithStuff(something, stuff)
    )
  );
}
```

Do you see a way to improve this code ?

Comment: @nicolas-van: I've added a serial version to the answer