# Type 'Observable<Subscription>' is not assignable to type Observable<MyData> rxjs angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

In angular I have created a service that gets the data from different service and merge the data with the first service. Here is the code

```
searchData(): Observable<MyData> {
    const url = `${this.context}/search`;
    return this.http.get<MyData>(url)
        .pipe(
            map((myData: MyData) => {
                return this.secondService.getOtherData().subscribe((data) => {
                    // some manipulation
                    return myData;
                });
            }));
}
```

but this is showing the error

```
Type 'Observable<Subscription>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MyData>'.
  Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'MyData': data, dataCount
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: two issues. Subscribe doesn’t return anything and if you are trying to return an inner observable you need to use something like switchMap or mergeMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. RxJS operator `map` is used to manipulate the emitted data from an observable and forward it.

#### Option 1: dependent observables

To map from one observable to another, you'd need to use a higher order mapping operator like `switchMap`.

```js
searchData(): Observable<MyData> {
  const url = `${this.context}/search`;
  return this.http.get<MyData>(url).pipe(
    switchMap((myData: MyData) =>         // <-- `switchMap` here
      this.secondService.getOtherData().pipe( // <-- assuming `getOtherData()` depends on response from 1st call
        map((data: any) => {              // <-- `map` here
          // some manipulation
          return myData;
        })
      )
    )
  );
}
```

#### Option 2: independent observables

If the observables do not depend on each other, you could use something like RxJS `forkJoin` function to trigger the observable in parallel.

```js
searchData(): Observable<MyData> {
  const url = `${this.context}/search`;

  return forkJoin({
    myData: this.http.get<MyData>(url),
    secondData: this.secondService.getOtherData().pipe(  // <-- assuming `getOtherData()` doesn't depend on response from 1st call
      map((data: any) => {
        // some manipulation
        return manipulatedData;
      })
    )
  });
}
```

In this case you'd get both the responses in the subscription.

```js
this.searchData().subscribe({
  next: (res: any) => {
    // res.myData
    // res.secondData
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) for more information on avoiding nested subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify `map` to `switchmap`.

```
searchData(): Observable<MyData> {
    const url = `${this.context}/search`;
    return this.http.get<MyData>(url)
        .pipe(
            switchMap((myData: MyData) => {
                return this.secondService.getOtherData().subscribe((data) => {
                    // some manipulation
                    return myData;
                });
            }));
}
```

Comment: Return pipe with map for the inner observable

Answer (score 0):

This is because your function return type is `Observable<MyData>` and in the `map` function you are returning a `subscription`

```js
    searchData(): Observable<MyData> {
        const url = `${this.context}/search`;
        return this.http.get<MyData>(url).pipe(
             switchMap((myData: MyData) => this.secondService.getOtherData())
        );
    }
```

you have to subscribe to `searchData()` method which will subscribe to outer and inner observables.
You can use `tap` operator to get data from these apis separately.

```js
    searchData(): Observable<MyData> {
        const url = `${this.context}/search`;
        return this.http.get<MyData>(url).pipe(
             tap(myData => console.log(myData)),
             switchMap((myData: MyData) => this.secondService.getOtherData()),
             tap(otherData => console.log(otherData))
        );
    }
```