# Is there any way to combine following two Observable into a array of object in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Suppose we have two observables

```
 student$ = from([
    {id: 1, name: "Alex"},
    {id: 2, name: "Marry"},
  ])

  address$ = from([
    {id: 1, location: "Chicago", sid: 1},
    {id: 2, location: "Florida", sid: 2},
  ])
```

I want to combine them into a array of object, the expected result would be following

```
  studentAddress = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Alex",
      address: [
        {id: 1, location: "Chicago", sid: 1},
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Marry",
      address: [
        {id: 2, location: "Florida", sid: 2},
      ]
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Does your first observable response depends on the second ? Like once you get first data you need to pass it to second to receive the address right?

Comment: @WahabShah Yes like a nested HTTP request.

Comment: @jabaa i am newbie at this stack, could you give me an example?

Comment: @SifulIslamOvi: The mock data you've provided for the use case you've mentioned is wrong. `from` function would emit the array elements one-by-one. You should've used `of` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your `students$` and `address$` observable emits an array of objects.

```
  address$ = of([
    { id: 1, location: 'Chicago', sid: 1 },
    { id: 2, location: 'Florida', sid: 2 },
  ]);

  students$ = of([
    { id: 1, name: 'Alex' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Marry' },
  ]);
```

Use RxJs function [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest): It Combines multiple Observables to create an Observable whose values are calculated from the latest values of each of its input Observables.

`combineLatest` will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value

```
combineLatest(
  [this.students$, this.address$],
  (students, address) =>
    students.map((s) => ({
      ...s,
      address: address.filter((a) => a.sid === s.id),
    })) // combineLatest also takes an optional projection function
).subscribe(console.log);
```

imports used :

```
import { combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
```

Angular [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sujdh2) by using `combineLatest` and `forkJoin`

Note: In your case instead of `combibeLatest` you can use [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin). `forkJoin` only emits value When all observables are complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use flatMap for that (RxJs method). Your first value would be needed by the second one. I am pasting an example code snippet below for flatMap() and also the article link there are other methods as well (the below example is from the same article link)

```
let first = Observable.of(10);
first.flatMap((operand1) => {
  return Observable.of(operand1 + 10);
 })
.subscribe(res => this.flatMappedStreams = {msg: '10 + 10 = ' + res});
```

Check out this [article here](https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/combining-multiple-rxjs-streams-in-angular-2.0) for `concat`, `combine`, `forkJoin` etc

But the important thing is the way to achieve is RxJs Operators. You can also refer to their [official docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators) for further understanding

Answer (score 0):

Taken from your comment that the arrays are obtained from nested HTTP calls, I'd say you need

- [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operator to map from one HTTP call to another (other [higher order mapping operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921))
- [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator to transform the emission from the observable
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do the actual combination of the arrays

```js
var { of } = rxjs;
var { switchMap, map } = rxjs.operators;

const students$ = of([
  {id: 1, name: "Alex"},
  {id: 2, name: "Marry"},
]);

const addresses$ = of([
  {id: 1, location: "Chicago", sid: 1},
  {id: 2, location: "Florida", sid: 2},
]);

const result$ = students$.pipe(
  switchMap(students =>
    addresses$.pipe(
      map(addresses => 
        students.map(student => ({
          ...student,
          address: addresses.filter(address => address.id === student.id)
        }))
      )
    )
  )
);

result$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```