# RxJS operator that waits for completion and then emits one value

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular2-observables, reactivex

Is there an RxJS operator that waits until the source completes and then emits a given value? If there is none, how could I provide it on my own?

This would work similar to `toArray()` which also waits for the source to complete. Instead of collecting all the emitted values, I want to ignore them and return a different value instead.

Here is an equivalent implementation:

```
observable.pipe(
  ignoreElements(),
  endWith(myValue),
);
```

alternatively:

```
observable.pipe(
  toArray(),
  map(ignore => myValue)
)
```

There are often situations where I need this. I came to the conclusion that it's dangerous to convert promise `then`-chains to observables by `switchMap()` or `mergeMap()` because inner observables could complete without emitting a value at all. Recently we had this problem:

```
return getEntitiesFromBackend().pipe(
  switchMap(entities => {
    return putEntitiesToObjectStore(entities);
  }),
  switchMap(() => {
    return storeSyncDate();
  })
);
```

In some situations the sync date wasn't stored and it was hard to find out why. In the end, the reason was that the `putEntities...` method emits a value for its "put"-operation. But in those cases the `entities` array was empty, so no value was emitted at all.

This is what I actually wanted to do - translated to the promise world:

```
return getEntitiesFromBackend()
  .then(entities => {
    return putEntitiesToObjectStore(entities);
  })
  .then(() => {
    return storeSyncDate();
  })
);
```

Most of the code I saw which uses `switchMap` / `mergeMap` doesn't have this problem. Because most of the time you deal with HTTP requests that only emit once and then completes. See [here](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/10/journey-promises-to-rxjs/) for example. This made me getting used to convert typical promise patterns to the RxJS world with `switchMap` without thinking too much about it's actual working and purpose.
Now, that we work with IndexedDB most of our methods return observables that emit a value for each DB operation. `switchMap` / `mergeMap` will get a nightmare here.

This is why I'm asking for such an operator and wonder why I couldn't find it yet, as it's such a common case in our application. I could easily solve this by using the alternative implementations above, but don't want to repeat those two operators over and over again:

```
return getEntitiesFromBackend().pipe(
  switchMap(entities => {
    return putEntitiesToObjectStore(entities);
  }),
  ignoreElements(),
  endWith(),
  switchMap(() => {
    return storeSyncDate();
  })
);
```

Of course I could use `toArray()` and just ignore the argument in the next operator. I don't like it because it would cause an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest two changes.

1. Use `concatMap` instead of `switchMap` or `mergeMap`. `concatMap` would ensure each emission from the `getEntitiesFromBackend()` Observable would be forwarded sequentially one after other and not in parellel (`mergeMap`) or would get cancelled (`switchMap`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) for a brief intro to different types of higher order mapping operators.
2. Instead of combination of operators like `ignoreElements` + `map` you could use the [`last`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/last) operator with a predicate that always returns `false` with a default value. This way the default value would be emitted when the source observable completes.

```js
return getEntitiesFromBackend().pipe(
  concatMap(entities => {
    return putEntitiesToObjectStore(entities).pipe(
      last(() => false, myValue),
    );
  }),
  concatMap((myValue) => {
    return storeSyncDate();
  })
);
```

Comment: The problem is that `putEntitiesToObjectStore` could complete without emitting a value at all. From my understanding `concatMap` won't emit anything. `last()` doesn't work, because no value is emitted.

Comment: @fishbone: In that case you could just pipe the `last` to the `putEntitiesToObjectStore(entities)` directly. I've updated my answer. Please see if it works.

Comment: `last()` has a second parameter? This is missing here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last  I didn't notice it. Well in this case your previous answer version should also work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @fishbone: Yes it does. The [official doc](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/last) mentions it. The signature in learnrxjs.io is probably wrong. Their [example 3](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last#examples) actually has a `defaultValue` argument `'Nothing'`. And yes, you are right, the `last` should be triggered regardless of where it's piped in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A few options come to mind.

#### `defaultIfEmpty`

This isn't exactly what you're describing, but it may fit your usecase.

> **defaultIfEmpty:** Emits a given value if the source Observable completes without emitting any next value, otherwise mirrors the source Observable.

```ts
return getEntitiesFromBackend().pipe(
  switchMap(entities => putEntitiesToObjectStore(entities)),
  defualtIfEmpty(null),
  switchMap(_ => storeSyncDate())
);
```

#### Create your own operator

There is a static version of `pipe` that performs composition without the application to any given stream.

So, for example:

```ts
const a = source.pipe(
  ignoreElements(),
  endWith(myValue)
);

const b = pipe(
  ignoreElements(),
  endWith(myValue)
);
```

Here, `a` is an observable. Pipe composes two operators, then returns the result of applying the composed operator to the `source`.

`b` on the other hand is just the first step. `b` is an operator itself. The operator hasn't get been applied to an observable.

So you can do something like this:

```ts
source1.pipe(b);
source2.pipe(b);
```

I've re-used my `b` operator twice. We're most of the way there!

RxJS operators are so useful because they're returned by functions that customize the operator to your needs. In the above case, every time you use `b`, you'll have the same value for `endwith`.

We can wrap b in a function to get that customized on a per-use basis.

```ts
const myCustomOperator = myValue => pipe(
  ignoreElements(),
  endWith(myValue)
);

source1.pipe(
  myCustomOperator(22)
);

source2.pipe(
  myCustomOperator(23)
);
```

This works just like any other operator, so it can be composed (be "piped") with all the other standard operators too.

> I could easily solve this by using the alternative implementations above, but don't want to repeat those two operators over and over again:

Now you have a re-usable piece of code!

---

#### How I would implement this:

JavaScript:

```js
function ignoreThenConcat(genObs) {
  return pipe(
    ignoreElements(),
    concatWith(from(genObs()))
  );
}

[...]
  return getEntitiesFromBackend().pipe(
    switchMap(entities => putEntitiesToObjectStore(entities)),
    ignoreThenConcat(() => storeSyncDate())
  );
[...]
```

I find that seeing code statically typed often really helps my understanding. So here's the same thing in TypeScript:

```ts
function ignoreThenConcat<T,R>(genObs: () => ObservableInput<R>): OperatorFunction<T,R> {
  return pipe(
    ignoreElements(),
    concatWith(from(genObs()))
  );
}

[...]
  return getEntitiesFromBackend().pipe(
    switchMap(entities => putEntitiesToObjectStore(entities)),
    ignoreThenConcat(() => storeSyncDate())
  );
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds to me like you want to achieve this:

```
source.pipe(
   last(), // emits only last value, when the source completes
   map(() => myValue), // or mapTo(myValue)
)
```

Comment: From my understanding this won't work: I assume that `last()` won't emit a value if source doesn't emit a value. And none-emitting observables are the main problem here.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `finalize` operator?

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize

Comment: finalize is rather a `tap` analogue for the finishing. Question author looks on how to emit one event in the end, not to do some side finishing logic while dealing with the observable

Answer (score 0):

This is my try, but I don't know if it works correctly (i.e. treats errors correctly etc.)

```
function emitOnComplete(value) {
  return function<T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
      return source.subscribe({
        next() {},
        complete() {
          subscriber.next(value);
          subscriber.complete();
        }
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Alternatively I came up with this, but it's untested:

```
function emitOnComplete(value) {
  return function <T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return source.pipe(
      ignoreElements(),
      // concat() is used to make sure we emit the value AFTER source completed
      // The tick is: source will never emit any value, because we use ignoreElements() above.
      // So the user will only get `of(value)`, but after the source is completed
      s => concat(s, of(value)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `() => concat(source, of(value))` won't work as it resubscribes to the source. Instead, you'd want `s => concat(s, of(value))`. That already has a name though, it's `concatWith(of(value))`.

Comment: Ah yes of course, that was the wrong source, thanks. I kept `concat` because with the comment above I think it's easier to understand.