# Iterate through Observable object-array and add additional data from another Observable to every object

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable

I have a Angular service returning an array of "cleaningDuty" objects. Inside a duty object, there is a nested object called "currentCleaner" with an id.

```
[
  {
    // other cleaningDuty data
    currentCleaner: {
      id: string;
      active: boolean;
    };
  },
  {
    // other cleaningDuty data
    currentCleaner: {
      id: string;
      active: boolean;
    };
  },
  {
    // other cleaningDuty data
    currentCleaner: {
      id: string;
      active: boolean;
    };
  }
]
```

with the help of the `currentCleaner.id` I want to fetch the user data of the currentCleaner from a UserService dynamically in the same `pipe()` method and add the returned user data to the cleaningDuty object. Then the object should look like this:

```
{
  // other cleaningDuty data
  currentCleaner: {
    id: string;
    active: boolean;
  },
  cleanerData: {
    name: string;
    photoUrl: string;
    // other user data
  }
},
```

Unfortunately I just cant get this to work even after investing days into it. I tried almost every combination from `forkJoin()`, `mergeMap()` and so on. I know a nested `subscribe()` method inside the target component would get the job done, but I want to write the best code possible quality-wise. This is my current state of the service method (it adds the user observable instead of the value to the cleaningDuty object):

```
getAllForRoommates(flatId: string, userId: string) {
    return this.firestore
      .collection('flats')
      .doc(flatId)
      .collection('cleaningDuties')
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((duties) => {
          let currentCleaners = duties.map((duty) =>
            this.userService.getPublicUserById(duty.currentCleaner.id),
          );
          return forkJoin([currentCleaners]).pipe(
            map((users) => {
              console.log(users);
              duties.forEach((duty, i) => {
                console.log(duty);
                duty.cleanerInfos = users[i];
              });
              return duties;
            }),
          );
        }),
      );
  }
```

The `getPublicUserById()` method:

```
getPublicUserById(id: string) {
    return this.firestore.collection('publicUsers').doc(id).valueChanges();
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) function will:

> Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last values they emitted; complete immediately if an empty array is passed.

So, you have to make sure that all the inner Observables have been completed, then the `forkJoin` will emit the combined values, and you can achieve that using [take(1)](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/take) operator, like the following:

```js
getAllForRoommates(flatId: string, userId: string) {
  return this.firestore
    .collection('flats')
    .doc(flatId)
    .collection('cleaningDuties')
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((duties) =>
        // The `forkJoin` will emit its value only after all inner observables have been completed.
        forkJoin(
          duties.map((duty) =>
            // For each duty, fetch the cleanerData, and append the result to the duty itself:
            this.userService.getPublicUserById(duty.currentCleaner.id).pipe(
              take(1), // to complete the sub observable after getting the value from it.
              map((cleanerData) => ({ ...duty, cleanerData }))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: If I do a simple subscribe + console.log of the result in my desired component, it still doesn't emit anything. I attached the getPublicUserById() method in the original post if that is the problem

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem is that `getPublicUserById` observable is not completed after emitting the value, so the `forkJoin` won't emit any value.

Comment: Thats what I was missing all day long, thank you!

Comment: Do you have an alternate solution for when you don't have ` .valueChanges()` method available in the first observable. When I do this, it only returns one object. Does not iterate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you need `switchMap` or `mergeMap`. IMO I'd cancel the existing observable when the `valueChanges()` emits. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) for the difference b/n them.
2. Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) function to trigger the requests in parallel.
3. Use RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax to add additional properties to existing objects.
4. Ideally defined types should be used instead of `any` type.

Try the following

```js
getAllForRoommates(flatId: string, userId: string) {
  return this.firestore
    .collection('flats')
    .doc(flatId)
    .collection('cleaningDuties')
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(
      switchMap((duties: any) =>
        forkJoin(
          duties.map((duty: any) =>          // <-- `Array#map` method
            this.userService.getPublicUserById(duty.currentCleaner.id).pipe(
              map((data: any) => ({          // <-- RxJS `map` operator
                ...duty,                     // <-- the `currentCleaner` property
                cleanerData: data            // <-- new `cleanerData` property
              }))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it still doesn't emit any data even when im doing a basic .subscribe(res => console.log(res)) in my desired component.

Comment: If it helps, I attached the getPublicUserById() method in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would suggest you to improve the typings on your application, that will help you to see the issue more clear.
For my answer I will assume you have 3 interfaces defined CurrentCleaner, CleanerData and RoomData wich is just:

```
interface RoomData {
    currentCleaner: CurrentCleaner
    cleanerData: CleanerData
}
```

Then you can write a helper function to retrieve the room data from a current cleaner:

```
getRoomData$(currentCleaner: CurrentCleaner): Observable<RoomData> {
    return this.userService.getPublicUserById(currentCleaner.id).pipe(
        map(cleanerData => ({ currentCleaner, cleanerData }))
    )
}
```

As you can see, this functions take a current cleaner, gets the cleaner data for it and maps it into a RoomData object.

Having this next step is to define your main function

```
getAllForRoommates(flatId: string, userId: string): Observable<RoomData[]> {
    return this.firestore
        .collection('flats')
        .doc(flatId)
        .collection('cleaningDuties')
        .valueChanges()
        .pipe(
            mergeMap((duties) => {
                // here we map all duties to observables of roomData
                let roomsData: Observable<RoomData>[] = duties.map(duty => this.getRoomData$(duty.currentCleaner));

                // and use the forkJoin to convert Observable<RoomData>[] to Observable<RoomData[]>
                return forkJoin(roomsData)
            }),
        );
    }
```

I think this way is easy to understand what the code is doing.