# How to handle error and return observable while subscribe inside an observable function in Rxjs Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to check one api call inside an observable which I will subscribe in a component. As written below, I want to run my observable in this manner but it is not working. What changes shall I do to this code to make it work. Whenever I try to subscribe through it especially through the scenario when someObservableWrittenInTheSameService returns with an error 404, I want to return url2.

```
getfunction(submissionId: string ){

if (some condition) {
   this.someObservableWrittenInTheSameService(parameter).subscribe(
    (httpValue: any) => {
      let url = '';
      if (httpValue.code === 200) {
         return this.http.get(url1); 
      }
    }, err => {
      if (err.code === 404) {
        return this.http.get(url2);
      }
      
    }
  )
}

  let url3
  return this.http.get(url3);
}
```

This function is then is called in a component where it is subscribed. But whenever someObservableWrittenInTheSameService return 404, the subscription always fails and go to error block in the component.

Comment: You should watch `catchError` operator to check if it match your expectations https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError

Comment: Your question is not clear `This function is then is called in a component where it is subscribed. But whenever someObservableWrittenInTheSameService return 404, the subscription always fails and go to error block in the component.` . This is working as expected

Comment: @MaximeChevallier Yeah solution would involve this.

Comment: @brk It is not working as intended. I followed the approach given by ruth to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could use RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif) function to return an observable conditionally.
2. Use RxJS higher order mappping operator `switchMap` to map from one observable to another. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921).
3. Use [`catchError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) operator to perform error handling. From it's body you could either return the HTTP request or forward the error (using [`throwError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError)) or even complete the observable (using [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant) based on your requirement.

Try the following

```js
import { Observable, EMPTY, iif, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

getfunction(submissionId: string): Observable<any> {      // <-- observable must be returned here
  const obs1$ = this.someObservableWrittenInTheSameService(parameter).pipe(
    switchMap((httpValue: any) => 
      iif(
        () => httpValue.code === 200,
        this.http.get(url1),
        EMPTY                                             // <-- complete the observable if code is other than 200
      )
    ),
    catchError((error: any) =>                            // <-- `catchError` operator *must* return an observable
      iif(
        () => error.code === 404,
        this.http.get(url2),
        throwError(error)                                 // <-- you could also return `EMPTY` to complete the observable
      )
  )

  const obs2$ = this.http.get(url3);

  return iif(
    () => someCondition,
    obs1$,
    obs2$
  );
}
```

In this case you'd subscribe to the `getFunction()` function where it's used.

For eg.

```js
this.getFunction('some value').subscribe({
  next: (value: any) => { },
  error: (error: any) => { },
  complete: () => { }
});
```