# Why Angular function does not wait for the data load for HighChart?

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

Below is the code, I have tried async/ await too but doesn't work as expected, I always get undefined values in this.totalTwoChartData in getCharts() function?
I could expect null value but not undefined..
Should I cover all in one function only? or promise is the best way?
what is the best practice to write the clean code and handle these types of situations?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllChartData()
  }

  // Get all chart data
  getAllChartData() {
    // Do not call server api if callStartDate / callEndDates is null
    if (this.calStartDate !== null && this.calEndDate !== null) {
      this.getOneChartData();
      this.getTwoChartData();
      this.getThreeChartData();
      this.getCharts();
    }
  }

  // One chart data
  getOneChartData() {
    this.oneChartSubscription = this.chartService
      .getOneChartService(this.calStartDate, this.calEndDate)
      .pipe(filter((res) => res !== null))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.totalOneChartData = response.data
      })
  }

  // Two chart data
  async getTwoChartData() {
    this.twoChartSubscription = this.chartService
      .getTwoChartService(this.calStartDate, this.calEndDate)
      .pipe(filter((res) => res !== null))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.totalTwoChartData = response.data
      })
  }

  // Three chart data
  getThreeChartData() {
    this.threeChartSubscription = this.chartService
      .getThreeChartService(this.calStartDate, this.calEndDate)
      .pipe(filter((res) => res !== null))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.totalThreeChartData = response.data
      })
  }


  async getCharts() {
    // Load Two chart data
    if (await this.totalTwoChartData !== null) {
      var objOneChart = await this.totalOneChartData;
      this.arrOneName = Object.keys(objOneChart).map((k) => {
        return objOneChart[k]['Name'];
      });

      this.arrOneAmt = Object.keys(objOneChart).map((k) => {
        return parseFloat(objOneChart[k]['receivedAmount']);
      })....
```

Comment: You clearly misunderstood the concept of the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator. If you use it on values that are no promises, it will **not** wait until the value is set, instead a Promise will be created resolving immediately with the current value.

Comment: @JSONDerulo I may be wrong.. but If you see I have used async getTwoChartData() and then used await .. observables then subscribe itself return promise too..

Comment: First, you don't await the function, but the `this.totalTwoChartData` property. Second, an async function with an observable inside doesn't magically wait for the Observable to complete. It is possible to do implement it, e.g. with `toPromise()`, but your code doesn't, and it's not recommended.

Comment: @JSONDerulo, Now I understood why my code was not working! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a use-case for the `forkJoin` function (or `combineLatest` or `zip` based on the use-case) to trigger all the observables in parallel and proceed when they have emitted.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) for more info.

If you're again trying to use the variables `this.arrOneName` and `this.arrOneAmt` synchronously somewhere else in the controller (*.ts file), then you'd need to essentially move the subscription to that place. As a rule of thumb, subscribe to the observables where it's emissions are needed.

```js
getCharts() {
  forkJoin({
    oneChartData: this.chartService.getOneChartService(this.calStartDate, this.calEndDate).pipe(filter(res => !!res)),
    twoChartData: this.chartService.getTwoChartService(this.calStartDate, this.calEndDate).pipe(filter(res => !!res)),
    threeChartData: this.chartService.getThreeChartService(this.calStartDate, this.calEndDate).pipe(filter(res => !!res)),
  }).subscribe({
    next: (data: any) => {
      this.arrOneName = Object.keys(data.oneChartData).map((k) => objOneChart[k]['Name']);
      this.arrOneAmt = Object.keys(data.oneChartData).map((k) => parseFloat(objOneChart[k]['receivedAmount']));
      },
    error: (error: any) => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Just to add, it's in general a bad idea to mix Observables with Promises, and one should stick to either one of them.

Comment: Working like a charm! Just one question @ruth is it ok if we do not use return when after map?

Comment: @Raj: The statements `map((k) => objOneChart[k]['Name'])` is equivalent to `map((k) => { return objOneChart[k]['Name']; })`. So when the statements are enclosed in parentheses, `return` needs to be stated explicitly. For single line statements, the return value of that statement is returned to the arrow function.