# Sending multi http request in angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, typescript, spring, rxjs

I have a `Demand` class which has a list of `Contract`
When I get the Demand I receive both Demand and Contract in body response. This is my Json response when getting demand Object using this url

(`http://localhost:8080/v1/demande/getDemande/1`):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "codeProduct": 14,
    "demandeType": "string",
    
    "contracts": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "contractType": "string",
            "endDate": "2022-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00",
            "startDate": "2022-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00",
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is my Json object when trying to retrieve only Contract Object using this url (`http://localhost:8080/v1/demande/getContrat/2`)

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "contractType": "string",
    "endDate": "2022-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00",
    "startDate": "2022-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00",
}
```

My goal is that I want to send first request to get `Demand` Object because I need that contract id, and after I get the id of contract I have to send another request to get the `Contract` Object

Is there any example ?
Thank you really appreciate your help.

Comment: It just depends on your implementation. It is not framework specific problem. Did you debug your code?

Comment: You could use a higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to switch from one request to another. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) post for more info.

Comment: Demand contains a list of Contracts. Which contract do you want to get? the first?